# In what way is a Nazir holy?

Tags: kedusha-holiness, nozir

Numbers 6:5 - 'Until the time is completed for which he separates himself to the Lord, he shall be holy.'

What does it mean to be holy in the eyes of the LORD?

https://biblehub.com/interlinear/numbers/6-5.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.6.5?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Numbers.6.5.1&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) (a preeminent biblical commentator) explains that this verse refers to the hair, not the Nazir.

> ["it" not "he"]: his hair shall be holy inasmuch as he must let grow
> freely the hair of his head

You are correct however that a Nazir is holy as it says in [Numbers 6:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.6.8?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) (transl. Artscroll)

> All the days of his abstinence he is holy to Hashem

In Judaism, holy often has a connotation of separate. A Nazir separates himself from cutting his hair, wine and dead people. By doing so, a Nazir aims to separate himself from the mundane by observing a meticulous lifestyle to get closer to God.

For more see [this Chabad article](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/287358/jewish/The-Nazir-and-the-Nazirite-Vow.htm).

Comment: Was it considered a vow offering as in an exchange for something? ie: I will take a Nazir vow until my wish is fulfilled?

Comment: One who declares he is a Nazir declares for how long (if not the standard term is 30 days). The end is not conditional on a specific wish. But it is possible to state  the term starts upon a certain event, e.g., "I am a Nazirite when I will have a child" (see [Mishna Nazir 2:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Nazir.2.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))